# After fixing the initial mistake, I am getting a blank page while trying to render HTML within my Flask app with Jinja code inside of it

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I would like to pull the second title from json data on a site. I'm able to pull up the json at https://api.npoint.io/82975389c85afb34e389 without a problem, but nothing shows up when I run my app with the attached code below. It is just blank and when I inspect the page, that code isn't there. Here is the code:

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/blog") 
def blog():     
  blog_url = "https://api.npoint.io/82975389c85afb34e389"     
  response = requests.get(blog_url)     
  all_posts = response.json()     
  return render_template("blog.html", posts=all_posts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

blog.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Fake Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% for blog_post in all_posts: %}
      {% if blog_post["id"] == "2": %}
          <h1>{{ blog_post["title"] }}</h1>
          <h2>{{ blog_post["subtitle"] }}</h2>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `{% for blog_post in blogs: %}` should be `{% for blog_post in all_posts: %}`

Comment: My god, it's always some variable I mess up. It's still blank though...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing posts=all_posts.

So your Jinja template will receive the posts as ‘posts’ so change it to say all_posts=all_posts and it should appear.

Comment: Bless you. I've been trying to figure it out for hours. Thank you so much

Comment: What's worse is she used blog=all_posts and hers worked...